# Does anyone know of a free H263 Plus Decoder codec

Tags: c++, codec, libavcodec, video-codecs

I am working on audio/video app &  looking for a H263Plus (not H263) decoder to be used in the project(C++ based)

Regards,
Chuks

Answer (score 1):

H263+ aka H263v2 is supported by libavcodec.

Comment: Ok, liavcodec is free to be distributed in commercial software?  I have one more question. How to find GOB in H263 Frames

Comment: @user470728 If you have one more question, please create another thread for it.